# Search returns too irrelevant results

Tags: php, symfony, elasticsearch, ongr

I am trying to get a full-text search work with ONGRFilterManagerBundle.
Everything is configured and added to the project but as soon as I ran a search on some data I found that the search returns completely irrelevant results.

here is my config:

```
ongr_elasticsearch:
  managers:
    default:
      index:
        hosts:
        - "%env(ELASTIC_HOST)%:%env(ELASTIC_PORT)%"
        index_name: project_search
      mappings:
      - SearchBundle

ongr_filter_manager:
  managers:
    search_list:
      filters:
      - content
      - pagination
      repository: es.manager.default.typed_content
  filters:
    content:
      type: match
      request_field: text
      document_field: content
    pagination:
      type: pager
      request_field: page
      document_field: ~
      options:
        count_per_page: 12
        max_pages: 8
```

and here is my document

```
namespace SearchBundle\Document;

use ONGR\ElasticsearchBundle\Annotation as ES;

/**
 * @ES\Document()
 */
class TypedContent implements DocumentInterface
{
    /**
     * @ES\Id()
     * @var string
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ES\Property(type="text")
     * @var string
     */
    private $content;

    /**
     * @ES\Property(type="text")
     * @var string
     */
    private $type;

    /**
     * @var mixed
     */
    private $dataObject;

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $id
     */
    public function setId($id): void
    {
        $this->id = $id;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getContent()
    {
        return $this->content;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $content
     */
    public function setContent($content): void
    {
        $this->content = $content;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getType(): string
    {
        return $this->type;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $type
     */
    public function setType(string $type): void
    {
        $this->type = $type;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getDataObject()
    {
        return $this->dataObject;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $dataObject
     */
    public function setDataObject($dataObject): void
    {
        $this->dataObject = $dataObject;
    }
}
```

When I search for example the word `olive` I will get a resultset of all my documents, although none of them contain a word that is remotely similar to "olive" and the score is "1" on every result.

Who can spot my mistake?

Comment: At least you'd have to share the query you're making.

Comment: Did you check what query is generated in the profiler tab? You should start from the query and analyzers and only then configure the filter manager accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I know now what the problem is. I am using a Symfony form to submit the search terms. In this case the name of the field is `search[text]` but the Manager is expecting the field to be of name `text`. So naturally the search will simply not take the searchterm into account. I will need to change the form to give the field the name `text` instead of `search[text]`